# undefined reference to c function when calling from go code

Tags: c, go, cgo

Im trying to call a simple c function from within go with cgo

The files are as follows:

*goFile.go:*

```
package main

//#include "cFile.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    C.printInC()
}
```

*cFile.h:*

```
void printInC();
```

*cFile.c:*

```
#include "cFile.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void printInC(){
    printf("Test");
}
```

running `go build goFile.go` throws the following exception:

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b001\_x002.o: in function `_cgo_f9774dcf54b4_Cfunc_printInC':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:49: undefined reference to `printInC'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not really sure why this isn't working, I've looked at multiple tutorials for cgo that implement calling c functions exactly the same way without a problem.

Comment: I am not familiar with Go but the important information would be how you tell Go which files to use. How do you tell Go to include the C code? Where did you tell Go to include cFile.c?

Comment: @Gerhardh: Through comments above `import "C"`. The compiler flags and linking information may also be mentioned if required.

Comment: There is only a comment for the header. No implementation included there.

Comment: @Gerhardh: The implementation is in `.c` file which is automatically referenced. It's just like C and C++ where the header file is included. But, you may also write your C or C++ code e.g. functions in the comments and reference those later in Go code. Here's an [example](https://onlinegdb.com/B115rWkYU).

Comment: In C you must include the C file to get the implementation. A header only provides declarations without implementation. If you only include the header, you will get the same "undefined reference" error.  According to your answer it seems to work now if you just include everything from the folder.

Comment: @Gerhardh: That's right. The source files are mentioned during compilation e.g. `gcc hello.c main.c -o hello`. In that example in my comment, the C code (implementation of `hello_world()` function) is part of the Go file. So, it's a standalone complete program and can be built with `go build <filename.go>`. In OP's case, the interface and implementation are in separate files so everything in the folder needs to be built and linked i.e. `go build` or `go build .`. I was hinting at this - single file and separate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem.

When running `go build goFile.go` the go tool apparently only builds goFile.go, when i run go build on the entire directory everything works fine..

Comment: `go build <filename.go>` may work if all the required code is included in that file. See this [example](https://onlinegdb.com/B115rWkYU).